# Bold text on tkinter canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How?  I've tried several variations of

```
self.textindex = self.canvastext.create_text(0,696,font=('freemono bold',9), anchor='nw', fill='black', text='Longitude: ' + str(px))
```

or

```
self.textindex = self.canvastext.create_text(0,696,font=('bold', 'freemono bold',9), anchor='nw', fill='black', text='Longitude: ' + str(px))
```

etc, to either have the font type revert back to the default font or to give me errors.

I actually want some type of font that is block style font, every character has the same width, so I can setup up nice column style formatting on parts of the screen.  I don't see on any programs I run, Times Roman(I think that is the right name) pop up so I'm guessing Linux Mint doesn't come standard with it:)..hence using freemono.  I would stick with the default font, which is already bold, trying to format it on the screen is a lot more difficult though and I'm in kinda for the looks given how nicely this program is turning out right now.

Comment: You might try reading some documentation instead of just trying random things. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm, http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/fonts.html, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_fonts.htm, http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/fonts.html

Comment: Actually I had used the Canvas widget effbot.org webpage to get as far as I got, but I didn't even think to go over to the other pages.  I thought I had tried it the way that it now works but I must not have been putting the quotes around bold.  Small stupid slip up.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to create a font object. For example:

```
# python2
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont as tkfont

# python3
# import tkinter as tk
# from tkinter import font as tkfont

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, background="bisque")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

normal_font = tkfont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12)
bold_font = tkfont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12, weight="bold")

canvas.create_text(50,50, text="This is normal", font=normal_font)
canvas.create_text(50,100, text="This is bold", font=bold_font)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: doesn't work in python 3. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call'. here's the way I imported it "import tkinter.font as TkFont". and call it "bold_font = TkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12, weight="bold")"

Comment: @AbdullahSaid: you must be doing something else wrong. The code as posted works for me in python3, even if I modify it to do the import the way you say you did.

Comment: turns out I forgot to put it under the root=tk.Tk(). i just put it before root = tk.Tk(). thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me (Python 3):

```
    canvas.create_text(x, y, font=('freemono', 11, 'bold'), anchor='sw', text=s)
```

And in addition to Bryan's answer: if you're using tkinter (as opposed to Tkinter) your code is:

```
    from tkinter import font
```

...

```
    myfont = font.Font(family='freemono', size=11, weight="bold")
    canvas.create_text(x, y, font=myfont, anchor='sw', text=s)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of changing the weight of the letters, you could change the font of the letters by saying (font="Ariel") but with the font that is thick enough for you. Hope this helped :)